# Jquery callback error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form to call ajax for back-end processing, all input will stored in table and will return 'success' to to notify user the submission is success. But I facing an issue during callback, input data can saved into table but the callback is halted with error below, I have no idea what is goes wrong, the same script was applied to another form (with different form field) are working pretty well, please help for solution.

*console log (Chrome):*

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
m.extend.each
$.ajax.success
j
k.fireWith
x
b
```

*Firefox*

```
TypeError: a is undefined

...rCase()},each:function(a,b,c){var d,e=0,f=a.length,g=r(a);if(c){if(g){for(;f>e;e...
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#status").hide();

        $('#btn_submit').click(function(){
            var params = $('#project_form').serialize();
            var btn = $(this);
            btn.button('loading')

            $.ajax({
                url: baseurl + '/process_form.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: params,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.success == 'success'){

                        $('#status').html('<b>Thank you</b>').show();

                        $('html,body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $('#top').offset().top
                        },500);

                    }else{
                        $('[id$="_error"]').html('');
                        $.each(response.error, function(key, value){
                            if(value){
                                $('#' + key + '_error').html(value);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log(arguments);
                }
            }).always(function(){
                btn.button('reset')
            });

        });

});
```

Comment: please add code of "process_form.php" file

Comment: we may need html too (of the form)

Comment: Is `response.error` defined, and a proper array/obect

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396833/jquery-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

first: When you want to use ajax with submit don't use submit click .. use form on submit better

```
$('#project_form').on('submit',function(){
            var params = $(this).serialize();
```

second: if in success you echo('success') in process_form.php you should use

```
if(response == 'success')
```

and use `response` instead of `response.error`

- Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the way you use the `success` callback method. The manual says:

> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback function, if specified; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object.

So it does not get a `.success` or `.error` passed along unless you yourself make sure it's returned from the url you are doing the ajax to. (If you are doing this, then don't read the rest of my answer, and use Element Inspector to see if the `.success` and `.error` are actually inside the returned data.)

So now your `if (response.success == "success")` is false, because it's actually undefined. And the `response.error` is also undefined, so `$.each(response.error, ...)` gives you your problem, since you cannot `.each` an undefined.

It is normal to just assume you are successful, since you are inside the success handler.